# Coin Tossing with probability P

Tags: probability

One hundred identical coins each with probability $P$ showing up heads are tossed

If $P$ lies in between $0$ and $1$

and the probability of heads showing on $50$ coins is equal to that of heads on $51$ coins, then the value of $P$ is?

The answer is $\frac{51}{101}$

Here is what i thought

the probability of getting 50 heads and tails is $P^{50}$.$(1-P)^{50}$

THIS IS EQUAL TO $P^{51}$.$(1-P)^{49}$

but that gives P =$\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: @probablyme what does that mean?

Comment: It means: Welcome to Math.SE. Please include your thoughts and efforts (work in progress) in this and future posts. 
You are more likely to receive positive/constructive feedback that way.  
Formatting your post helps too.
Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: The probability of $50$ heads is $\binom{100}{50}p^{50}(1-p)^{50}$. Use that, and the similar probability for $51$.

Comment: The probability of is given by a [binomial distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_distribution#Probability_mass_function)  so the probability that $50$ equals heads is $\binom{100}{50}P^{50}(1 - P)^{50}$ and the probability of 51 head is $\binom{100}{51}P^{51}(1 - P)^{49}$.

Comment: @Harish You can use the fact that $\binom{n}{k+1} = \binom{n}{k}\left(\frac{n-k}{k+1}\right)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of getting a sequence of 50 heads, followed by a sequence of 50 tails, is indeed $P^{50}(1-P)^{50}$. However, if you're just interested in whether there are 50 heads amongst all 100 coins, then you need to use the formula associated with the Binomial distribution. Are you familiar with that? The probability of getting $H$ heads and $100-H$ tails *in any order* is:

$P(H) = {{100}\choose{H}} P^H (1-P)^{100 - H}$

Where ${n\choose k} = \frac{n!}{k!(n-k)!}$ is the "chooose" function.

That should give you enough information to finish the question.

Comment: But why should u select them?

Comment: It's called the "choose" function because it's the number of different ways you can choose k objects out of n. In this case, it's the number of different (but functionally identical) ways you could pick H of the coins to be heads.

Answer (score 2):

You need to solve the following equation:

$$\binom{100}{50}\cdot(p)^{50}\cdot(1-p)^{50}=\binom{100}{51}\cdot(p)^{51}\cdot(1-p)^{49}$$

---

$\binom{100}{50}\cdot(p)^{50}\cdot(1-p)^{50}=\binom{100}{51}\cdot(p)^{51}\cdot(1-p)^{49}\implies$

$\frac{100!}{50!50!}\cdot(p)^{50}\cdot(1-p)^{50}=\frac{100!}{51!49!}\cdot(p)^{51}\cdot(1-p)^{49}\implies$

$(51!49!)\cdot(p)^{50}\cdot(1-p)^{50}=(50!50!)\cdot(p)^{51}\cdot(1-p)^{49}\implies$

$(51)\cdot(p)^{50}\cdot(1-p)^{50}=(50)\cdot(p)^{51}\cdot(1-p)^{49}\implies$

$(51)\cdot(1-p)=(50)\cdot(p)\implies$

$51-51p=50p\implies$

$101p=51\implies$

$p=\frac{51}{101}$

Comment: Thanks for it but why is your answer going out of the screen?

Comment: @Harish: It happens sometimes (at least on Firefox), I'm guessing due to the use of LaTex. Try to refresh the page.

Comment: Oh yes thanks  @barak

Answer (score 1):

You have forgotten the binomial coefficients needed for the binomial distribution.

Try $\binom{100}{50}p^{50}(1-p)^{50} = \binom{100}{51}p^{51}(1-p)^{49}$